# How to make matplotlib clipping to work on plot generated by rbf

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to use a patch on my plot to show only the points in a circle, the problem is that i am using an image generated with `Rbf` and it does not work.

Here is the last code i tried :

```
from scipy import  interpolate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches


x, y, z = 10 * np.random.random((3,10))
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

rbf = interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='linear')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4), facecolor='white')
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)

ax.imshow(zi, vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), origin='lower',
           extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])

something = ax.scatter(x,y)

patch = patches.Circle((1,1),radius=1,fc='none')
ax.add_patch(patch)
something.set_clip_path(patch)
fig1.show()
```

I am getting the following result, as you can see the values are showed in the whole rectangle, not only in a circle:

[image: result]

Comment: Why do you think this does not work? just put `fig.show()` in the last line of your code and you see that it works.

Comment: Thanks, updated my question but it still does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the position and the radius of the circle such that it actually includes some points from the random set, it will work as expected. To also clip the image itself, you need to set the clip patch to the image as well.

```
from scipy import  interpolate
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches


x, y, z = 10 * np.random.random((3,10))
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

rbf = interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='linear')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4), facecolor='white')
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)

im = ax.imshow(zi, vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), origin='lower',
           extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])

something = ax.scatter(x,y, c="crimson")

patch = patches.Circle((4,4),radius=3,fc='none')
ax.add_patch(patch)
something.set_clip_path(patch)
im.set_clip_path(patch)
plt.show()
```

[image]